# When posting a file with web api I get "Message: an error has occured" but it doesn't execute catch

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm new to web api and I'm getting an error that I don't understand. I'm using postman to test it. I have the following method in my controller that saves an uploaded file to a folder. It saves the file correctly but returns "Message: An error has occurred." It doesn't execute my error handler.

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostDocument()
{
    try
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Utilities.ErrorHandler("PostDocument", e);
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the end. First of all I switched off custom errors, like so:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

And this gave me a much more detailed error:

{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "The specified policy origin 'MyUrl' is invalid. It cannot end with a forward slash.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.ValidateOrigins(IList`1 origins)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.d__4.MoveNext()"
}

As you can see, it was all CORS related. I didn't actually need the CORS stuff and had only installed it to test something else, so I simply removed all traces of it in my code and voila.